# Google Maps OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier custom icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerspiderfier

I'd like to ask how to solve following problem:

We have a google map with few identical markers which are then *spiderified* with https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier and we would like to change the icon for them. In other words is there a way how to detect that the marker is *spiderified* to distinguish single marker from the one that will spring apart after the click?

Here is the demo source: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/gh-pages/demo.html

[image: Example of 2 markers that should have different icons]

Thanks

Comment: related question: [GeoJSON, Overlapping Pointers, OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656573/geojson-overlapping-pointers-overlappingmarkerspiderfier/), combines OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier and a MarkerClusterer.

Comment: @geocodezip they dont answer op question about *custom icon*. The only related question is this unanswered one [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier Marker Icon When There are Multiple Markers at Same Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829223/overlapping-marker-spiderfier-marker-icon-when-there-are-multiple-markers-at-sam?rq=1)